# Merge returns empty

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

There was a problem with the request. Any ideas?
The situation is as follows, there is a request

```
    MERGE ore as T_Base USING ( SELECT
        date
       ,sec
       ,shift
       ,id_ore
    FROM ore
    WHERE date = '2022-9-20'
    AND sec = '2'
    AND shift = '1') AS T_Source
ON T_Base.date = T_Source.date
    AND T_Base.sec = T_Source.sec
    AND T_Base.shift = T_Source.shift
    AND T_Base.id_ore = T_Source.id_ore
WHEN MATCHED
    THEN UPDATE
        SET date = T_Source.date
           ,sec = T_Source.sec
           ,shift = T_Source.shift
           ,id_ore = '1'
WHEN NOT MATCHED
    THEN INSERT (date, sec, shift, id_ore)
            VALUES (T_Source.date, T_Source.sec, T_Source.shift, '1');
```

But for some reason it returns "0 rows affected".

Table structure:

```
[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [date] [datetime] NULL,
    [sec] [int] NULL,
    [shift] [int] NULL,
    [id_ore] [int] NULL
```

Values in the table:

```
  id              date          sec shift   id_ore
11637   2022-09-10 00:00:00.000  1    1     13
11636   2022-09-09 00:00:00.000  1    2     13
etc
```

Expected Result

1. When updated, no change

   ```
    id              date            sec shift   id_ore
    11637   2022-09-10 00:00:00.000  1    1       13
   ```

1.1) When update, with changes (shift and id_ore updated )

```
 id              date           sec     shift       id_ore
11637   2022-09-10 00:00:00.000  1    2(change)   27(change)
```

2. When new values are inserted:

   ```
      id              date          sec shift   id_ore
    11638   2022-09-20 00:00:00.000  1    1       1
   ```

Comment: Perhaps there are no matching rows in your source. `WHERE date = '2022-9-20'` is odd... is it a `date` column or is it some kind of `char/varchar` column?

Comment: Given the column definition `[date] [datetime]`... Assuming it even parses correctly with your current `DATEFORMAT` settings, `WHERE date = '2022-9-20'` will only match rows that exactly match `2022-09-20 00:00:00.000` and ignore every other time throughout the day.

Comment: I need to compare the future date. If there are no rows, then insert the value

Comment: I'm assuming the problem is that my T_Source doesn't have that date yet

Comment: In fact, it's all about the date. If I take an existing date, the UPDATE operation goes through without problems. But if I take a date that is not yet in the database, then the INSERT operation will not work. I do not know why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for this post. I misunderstood the MERGE construction. If there is no data in any of the tables, the operation will not be performed, since there will be nothing to match
If suddenly, someone encountered a similar, came to the following solution:

```
 IF EXISTS (SELECT
              date
              ,sec
              ,shift
              FROM ore 
              WHERE date = '" . $y . "-" . $m . "-" . $d . "'
              AND sec = '" . $sec . "'
              AND shift = '" . $shift. "')
        UPDATE ore 
        SET id_ore  = '" . $nam_ryd . "'
        WHERE date = '" . $y . "-" . $m . "-" . $d . "'
        AND sec = '" . $sec . "'
        AND shift = '" . $shift. "'
        ELSE
        INSERT ore (date, sec, shift, id_ore)
            VALUES ('" . $y . "-" . $m . "-" . $d . "', '" . $sec . "', '" . $shift. "', '" . $nam_ryd . "')
```